# Django Admin - How can I select new data created using ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

For example, I have this models

```
# models.py
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)


class CategoryDescription(models.Model)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=120)


class Image(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    description = models.ForeignKey(CategoryDescription)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

And I have this admin init file

```
# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, CategoryDescription, Image


class CategoryDescriptionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CategoryDescription


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (CategoryDescriptionInline,)


class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)
```

I want create new Image in Admin, i create new category, using `plus` placed right from select input and next, i want choose Image Description, but i cant do it, because it isn't loaded.

What you may recommend for me in this situation? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a ModelAdmin for CategoryDescription, e.g.:

```
admin.site.register(CategoryDescription)
```

Comment: No-no, I want select Category Description when i create category in Image.

Comment: The reason you're getting a "plus" for Category and not for CategoryDescription is that you registered a ModelAdmin for Category but not for CategoryDescription.